# Show URL herf link with the use of id in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am having a summary page which will show all the customer name which is called readmsg.php and each of the customer has a unique msgid in MySQL database. The other page can view their details which are called readmsgdetail.php.

However, I am having the problem in using the msgid to display only one customer's details. For now, my readmsgdetail.php can show all the details for all customers.

The code for my readmsg.php:

```
       <div class="row">
        <?php
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,enquiry FROM user_message ORDER BY msgid DESC');
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                extract($row);
                ?>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p><a class="page-header" href="readmsgdetail.php?msgdetail_id=<?php echo $row['msgid']; ?>"><?php echo $lastname .  $firstname; ?></a></p>
                </div>       
                <?php
            }
        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

The code for my readmsgdetail.php:

```
    <?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
//////------------------------------------------------
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION) || empty($_SESSION['login_id'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
};
echo"Welcome!! " . $_SESSION['login_id'] . "   ";
echo '<a href="logout.php">log out</a>';
//-----------------------------------------------------

if (isset($_REQUEST['msgdetail_id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['msgdetail_id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['msgdetail_id'];
} else {

    header("Location: readmsg.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
        <title></title>
        <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


        <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>




        <div class="container">


            <div class="page-header">
                <h1 class="h2">User review <a class="btn btn-default" href="readmsg.php"> all reviews </a></h1>
            </div>



            <?php
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,enquiry FROM user_message ORDER BY msgid DESC');
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    extract($row);
                    ?>
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">




                        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

                            <tr>
                                <td><label class="control-label">Name.</label></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $lastname . $firstname; ?>" required /></td>
                            </tr>



                            <tr>
                                <td><label class="control-label">Phone </label></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" required /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><label class="control-label">Feedback / Enquiry.</label></td>

                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="comment" value="<?php echo $enquiry; ?>" required /></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="readmsg.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span> back </a>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>     
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                ?>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-warning">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The stucture of MySQL: 
[image]

The current result for the webpage:

[image]

After I change my select statement to

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,enquiry FROM user_message where msgid = 'msgdetail_id'");
```

It shows 'no data found'.

Comment: add a `WHERE` clause to `SELECT`.

Comment: after I change to "$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,enquiry FROM user_message where msgid = 'msgdetail_id'");" It shows no data found.

Comment: `where msgid = 'msgdetail_id'` that's because `msgid` is `int` and you're trying to pass off a string.

Comment: Here `where msgid = '$id'` that ought to fix your code.

Comment: ...and I'm betting someone will see my comment and post an answer; watch for it. Ok, I left this. If it solved it, you let me know. If it didn't, keep debugging this. I stayed longer than usual with no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in readmsg.php should change to :

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT msgid, firstname,lastname,phone,enquiry FROM user_message ORDER BY msgid DESC');
```

The code in readmsgdetail.php should change to:

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT firstname,lastname,phone,enquiry FROM user_message where msgid=$id");
```

This is woking now! Thx for the help from the comments!.